# Nimiety text with inserted data

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am trying to insert data in database (`WPF`). This is my connection code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
namespace sba1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ASUS\\SQL;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sc.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into prsn(id,name) values ('" + txtid + "' , '" + txtname + "')", sc);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("update sucsessful to database");
                sc.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`prsn` table have two columns (`id[unique]` - `name`). For example when I want to insert `name = Doe` with `id = 914524`, The result in table is :

```
id = system.windows.control.textbox: 914524
name = system.windows.control.textbox: Doe
```

Could somebody explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Text` property of `TextBox` like:

```
txtname.Text
```

You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.